# From these logs, does the memory usage of my Android game seem reasonable?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

I have written a game in Java for the Android platform which is currently undergoing thorough testing before it's release. It's all looking good in terms of bugs fixed, etc. but the thing which is troubling me at the moment is the memory usage.

It all looks fine when executing on an emulator hosting **Android 2.3.3 with 16MB VM Heap** as you can see from the following log dumps:

**Just after booting up before starting my game:**

```
05-23 15:11:43.422: DEBUG/dalvikvm(133): GC_EXPLICIT freed 81K, 50% free 2873K/5703K, external 6185K/6640K, paused 44ms 
05-23 15:11:45.222: DEBUG/dalvikvm(60): GC_EXPLICIT freed 164K, 45% free 4104K/7431K, external 4373K/5573K, paused 76ms
```

**After starting my game:**

```
05-23 15:12:40.762: DEBUG/dalvikvm(314): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 104K, 50% free 2833K/5575K, external 5104K/5748K, paused 46ms
05-23 15:12:41.143: DEBUG/dalvikvm(314): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 10K, 50% free 2841K/5575K, external 6046K/6103K, paused 46ms
05-23 15:12:42.202: DEBUG/dalvikvm(314): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 79K, 49% free 2925K/5639K, external 7656K/7658K, paused 46ms
```

So, from those entries it seems that I have around 50% available memory to use.

--

Now, when I start an emulator hosting **Android 4.1.2 with 32MB VM Heap**, the values I see from the logs are somewhat disappointing:

**Just after booting up before starting my game:**

```
05-23 15:08:32.566: DEBUG/dalvikvm(149): GC_CONCURRENT freed 530K, 6% free 9763K/10375K, paused 16ms+19ms, total 132ms
05-23 15:08:32.946: DEBUG/dalvikvm(149): GC_CONCURRENT freed 913K, 10% free 9786K/10823K, paused 16ms+27ms, total 128ms
```

**After starting my game:**

```
05-23 15:09:25.706: DEBUG/dalvikvm(618): GC_CONCURRENT freed 418K, 3% free 20563K/21063K, paused 18ms+19ms, total 118ms
05-23 15:09:25.706: DEBUG/dalvikvm(618): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 38ms
05-23 15:09:26.316: DEBUG/dalvikvm(618): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 557K, 4% free 21761K/22599K, paused 55ms, total 75ms
```

The amount of free memory hover around the 4%-10% mark despite the fact that this emulator has twice the amount of memory.

Initially, I thought it may be because the background graphic I am loading is larger (1280x800 pixels vs 800x480 pixels) but disproved this by removing the code that loads the background graphics and noticed that the amount of free memory remained the same.

Maybe I'm just paranoid and there isn't actually a problem because from the above logs it seems that immediately after booting up, the Android 4.1.2 instance reports between 6% and 10% of free memory anyway.

I have also added some manual memory usage logging for when the game was running on the Android 4.1.2 emulator. You will see from the following log entries, I have included the methods I used to obtain the values (e.g. Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()) :

```
05-23 15:09:26.386: DEBUG/Memory Usage(618): Heap Limit: 32(amount to stay within)
05-23 15:09:26.386: DEBUG/Memory Usage(618): Heap
05-23 15:09:26.386: DEBUG/Memory Usage(618): - Current Total: 23863264 (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory())
05-23 15:09:26.386: DEBUG/Memory Usage(618): - Maximum: 33554432 (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory())
05-23 15:09:26.386: DEBUG/Memory Usage(618): - Free: 792736 (Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())
05-23 15:09:26.386: DEBUG/Memory Usage(618): Native Heap
05-23 15:09:26.386: DEBUG/Memory Usage(618): - Allocated: 10139952 (Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize())
05-23 15:09:26.396: DEBUG/Memory Usage(618): - Size: 10383360 (Debug.getNativeHeapSize())
05-23 15:09:26.396: DEBUG/Memory Usage(618): - Free: 136912 (Debug.getNativeHeapFreeSize())
```

Any suggestions and/or comments would be most welcome.

Thanks for reading,
Wayne.